# Reduce handling of Optional by leveraging the type system?

Tags: rust, types, traits

I'm trying to access an api, where I can specify what kind of fields I want included in the result. (for example "basic", "advanced", "irrelevant"

the Rust Struct to represent that would look something like

```
Values {
  a: Option<String>;
  b: Option<String>;
  c: Option<String>;
  d: Option<String>;
}
```

or probably better:

```
Values {
  a: Option<Basic>;      // With field a
  b: Option<Advanced>;   // With fields b,c
  c: Option<Irrelevant>; // With field d
}
```

Using this is possible, but I'd love to reduce the handling of Option for the caller.
Is it possible to leverage the type system to simplify the usage? (Or any other way I'm not realizing?)

My idea was something in this direction, but I think that might not be possible with rust (at least without macros):

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=093bdf1853978af61443d547082576ca

```
struct Values {
    a: Option<&'static str>,
    b: Option<&'static str>,
    c: Option<&'static str>,
}

trait ValueTraits{}

impl ValueTraits for dyn Basic{}
impl ValueTraits for dyn Advanced{}
impl ValueTraits for Values{}

trait Basic {
    fn a(&self) -> &'static str;
}

trait Advanced {
    fn b(&self) -> &'static str;
    fn c(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl Basic for Values {
   fn a(&self) -> &'static str {
       self.a.unwrap()
   }
}

impl Advanced for Values {
    fn b(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.b.unwrap()
    }
    
    fn c(&self) -> &'static str {
        self.c.unwrap()
    }
}

//Something like this is probably not possible, as far as I understand Rust
fn get_values<T1, T2>() -> T1 + T2{
    Values {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "C"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let values = get_values::<Basic, Advanced>();
    println!("{}, {}, {}", values.a(), values.b(), values.c());
}
```

### Clarifications (Edit)

The Values struct contains deserialized json data from the api I called. I can request groups of fields to be included in the response(1-n requested fields groups), the fields are of different types.

If I knew beforehand, which of those fields are returned, I wouldn't need them to be Option, but as the caller decides which fields are returned, the fields needs to be Option (either directly, or grouped by the field groups)

There are too many possible combinations to create a struct for each of those.

I fully realize that this cannot work, it was just "peudorust":

```
fn get_values<T1, T2>() -> T1 + T2{
    Values {
        a: "A",
        b: "B",
        c: "C"
    }
}
```

But my thought process was:
In theory, I could request the field groups via generics, so I could create a "dynamic" type, that implements these traits, because I know which traits are requested.

The Traits are supposed to act like a "view" into the actual struct, because if they are requested beforehand, I know I should request them from the api to include them in the Struct.

My knowledge of generics and traits isn't enough to confidently say "this isn't possible at all" and I couldn't find a conclusive answer before I asked here.

Sorry for the initial question not being clear of what the actual issue was, I hope the clarification helps with that.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to do? It looks like it just calls `unwrap` everywhere. You may as well not have `Option`s if that's how you handle them.

Comment: @isaactfa looks like they want some sort of views system, where the view-cast would check that the view's requirements are met, then allow non-optional access to the relevant items (there the items themselves are optional).

Comment: @isaactfa I did not include any error handling, due to not being relevant for this example


I can request fields that will be included in the response from an API (Basic, Advance in this example) and I know they will be present in the response. But I'd like to have a function, where I can request any possible fields. Because I don't know what fields the caller will request, everything has to be an Option.


If I could use the type system to declare the fields that are present, I could just return their values instead of an Option

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite gauge whether or not you want to be able to request and return fields of multiple different types from the question. But if all the information being returned is of a single type you could try using a `HashMap`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_values(fields: &[&'static str]) -> HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> {
    let mut selected = HashMap::new();
    for field in fields {
        let val = match *field {
            "a" => "Value of a",
            "b" => "Value of b",
            "c" => "Value of c",
            // Skip requested fields that don't exist.
            _ => continue,
        };
        selected.insert(*field, val);
    }
    selected
}

fn main() {
    let fields = ["a","c"];
    let values = get_values(&fields);
    for (field, value) in values.iter() {
        println!("`{}` = `{}`", field, value);
    }
}
```

Additionally you've given me the impression that you haven't quite been able to form a relationship between generics and traits yet. I highly recommend reading over the book's ["Generic Types, Traits, and Lifetimes"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html?highlight=generics#generic-types-traits-and-lifetimes) section.

The gist of it is that generics exist to generalize a function, struct, enum, or even a trait to any type, and traits are used to assign behaviour to a type. Traits cannot be passed as a generic parameter, because traits are not types, they are behaviours. Which is why doing: `get_values::<Basic, Advanced>();` doesn't work. Basic and Advanced are both traits, not types.

If you want practice with generics try generalizing `get_values` so that it can accept any type which can be converted into an iterator that yields `&'static str`s.

---

**Edit:**
The clarification is appreciated. The approach you have in mind is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it because it's implementing it is extremely verbose and will panic the moment the format of the json you're parsing changes. Though if you really need to use traits for some reason you could try something like this:

```
// One possible construct returned to you.
struct All {
    a: Option<i32>,
    b: Option<i32>,
    c: Option<i32>,
}

// A variation that only returned b and c
struct Bc {
    b: Option<i32>,
    c: Option<i32>,
}

// impl Advanced + Basic + Default for All {...}
// impl Advanced + Default for Bc {...}
fn get_bc<T: Advanced + Default>() -> T {
    // Here you would set the fields on T.
    Default::default()
}

fn get_all<T: Basic + Advanced + Default>() -> T {
    Default::default()
}

fn main() {
    // This isn't really useful unless you want to create multiple structs that
    // are supposed to hold b and c but otherwise have different fields.
    let bc = get_bc::<Bc>();
    let all = get_all::<All>();
    // Could also do something like:
    let bc = get_bc::<All>();
    // but that could get confusing.

}
```

I think the above is how you're looking to solve your problem. Though if you can, I would still recommend using a `HashMap` with a trait object like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::Debug;

// Here define the behaviour you need to interact with the data. In this case
// it's just ability to print to console.
trait Value: Debug {}

impl Value for &'static str {}
impl Value for i32 {}
impl<T: Debug> Value for Vec<T> {}

fn get_values(fields: &[&'static str]) -> HashMap<&'static str, Box<dyn Value>> {
    let mut selected = HashMap::new();
    for field in fields {
        let val = match *field {
            "a" => Box::new("Value of a") as Box<dyn Value>,
            "b" => Box::new(2) as Box<dyn Value>,
            "c" => Box::new(vec![1,3,5,7]) as Box<dyn Value>,
            // Skip requested fields that don't exist.
            _ => continue,
        };
        selected.insert(*field, val);
    }
    selected
}

fn main() {
    let fields = ["a","c"];
    let values = get_values(&fields);
    for (field, value) in values.iter() {
        println!("`{}` = `{:?}`", field, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I added a clarification to my original question. The chapter of the book doesn't cover my question. I know that the way I used it in the example wasn't correct usage of Rust Generics, but I don't know how or if you can actually do the use  case I thought about. It seems it was more confusing then helpful though.

Comment: While the "Trait Solution" seems quite clumsy to me (multiple "get_xyz" methods, don't really make it feasable to use for me), the idea of an iterator over the fields seems like something that would solve my issue ( I would iterate over the field groups though - those can be an enum) - so thank you!